# .htaccess redirect all extension to php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, http, redirect

I recently updated my **.htaccess** file to hide the *.php extension* of the urls. It works nice, when I try to reach *domain.com/index*, it displays the php file.

When I type *domain.com/index.php* it redirects me to the *domain.com/index* url and displays the .php file as well.

I would like to redirect all other extensions to the no extension url to display the .php file for security reasons. My problem is, that I can not configure my **.htaccess** to redirect well known extensions like *.html .asp. aspx .shtml* etc. to the non-extension url, and get the .php file displayed as the content.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# php extension to no extension url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]


# no extension to the .php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# this is for the index
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Du you actually want to _redirect_ the .html etc. extensions the the files without extension or do you want to _rewrite_ the file names internally? I do not see a redirect in you code?!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Try these in your .htaccess file and please check if rewrite engine is on in server and there is mod_rewrite.c module is there in main apache conf file that is httpd.conf.

1.
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
OR
2.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Hope these work fine.

OR otherwise this is another option with all description:

Apache Rewrite Rules
 
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

## Add trailing slash to url

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

## Remove .php-extension from url

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ $1.php

## End of Apache Rewrite Rules

Things I guess you want to know:

1. This is for sites that don’t use a front-end-controller where all requests are forced through index.php. If you need that, you must replace the third block with your own.
2. The example is showed with .php only. If you want to use it with .html for example, you must copy/paste the third block and replace “.php” on line (1,) 3 and 4 with “.html” (unless someone has a neat way of doing it?)
3. The content of “example.com/something/” could be served from either “example.com/something.php” or “example.com/something/index.php”.
4. To link to other pages, just href=”/some/thing/” or href=”//example.com/some/thing/”.
5. With .css and .js you want to href=”/style.css” or href=”/folder1/style.css”. Else if you href=”style.css” from “example.com/folder2/file.php” it’ll look at “example.com/folder2/style.css”.

Note:  There is http:// in-front of all all example.com.

Answer (score 0):

if there's no other "." in your files except for the extension, did you try replacing ".php" by any string?

```
# php extension to no extension url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.\s+\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try The Below Code and change the extension whatever you want to hide:

1.For html file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

2.For php file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```